# How to get an opaque UINavigationBar on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, transparency

Is there any way to make the `UINavigationBar`, targeted for iOS 7, a solid color with no translucency?  I have tried setting the backgroundColor, the barTintColor, opaque, transparent/translucent, etc... and nothing works.

Anyone know how to do this?

Here are some chunks of code I have been using. Notice the properties I have set on the `navigationBar`. None of them, in any order or combination have worked.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:testViewController];

navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor;
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
navigationController.navigationBar.opaque = YES;

NSArray *tabBarViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      navigationController,
                                      anotherViewController, nil];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarViewControllers;
```

Comment: Post the code of how you are setting translucent.

Comment: Try to put `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` in your `testViewController`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your code lists navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

Set it to NO.

Answer (score 9):

To make it totally opaque u can just change the style of the navigation bar from the property section itself!

[image: Just set the style as Black!]

[image]

This is how it looks like when u make it black

Comment: I will try to translate that into code. I am not using xib's. Thanks.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. When I set barStyle to UIBarStyleBlack, my UITableView items still show through the UINavigationBar.

Comment: Then try removing translucency

Comment: Ok, what ive got from the details you have provided.
You have a UINavBar and UITableView in one view controller, fine?
Ive had this kind of problem before so i had used a container view for my UITable view.
I put the container view on the view controller where navbar is there and the table view in the Container's View controller!
Hope this works!

Answer (score 7):

To make all of your navigation bars opaque, you could just add `UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false` to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```